# Finishing stream unexpectedly when reading line by line using requests stream in nested loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am trying to read a text file line by line in a nested loop, jumping back and forth between reading in the outer loop and in the inner loop. However, the program ends with a StreamConsumedError or AttributeError before reaching the final line.

The program is the following. I am using a small public text file with 21 lines of Lorem Ipsum.

```
response = requests.get("https://filesamples.com/samples/document/txt/sample3.txt", stream=True)    
i = 0
for line in response.iter_lines():
    print(f"out: "+str(line)[0:10])
    i+=1
    if i<4: continue
    j = 0
    for line in response.iter_lines():
        print(f"in : "+str(line)[0:10])
        j+=1
        if j<2: continue
        i = 0
        break
```

In this case I would expect 4 lines starting with "out", followed by two lines starting with "in", and 4 with "out", 2 with "in" and so on, until the end of the file. I kinda get this in the beginning, but the second time the handler comes to the outer loop it reads five lines, and ends in a StreamConsumedError.

```
out i=1: b'Quod equ
out i=2: b'Lorem ip
out i=3: b''
out i=4: b'Iam id i
in  j=1: b'omina in
in  j=2: b''
out i=1: b''
out i=2: b'Quis ist
out i=3: b'Summus d
out i=4: b''
out i=5: b'Ex eorum
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
StreamConsumedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-163-e0b02f8d0863> in <cell line: 3>()
      6     if i<4: continue
      7     j = 0
----> 8     for iline in response.iter_lines():
      9         j+=1
     10         print(f"in  j={j}: "+str(iline)[0:10])
```

Would be awesome somebody could explain what is going on. Thank you in advance.

---

Just noted that th problem is apparently the repeated calls to `iter_lines()`.
This works:

```
response = requests.get("https://filesamples.com/samples/document/txt/sample3.txt", stream=True).iter_lines()    
i = 0
for oline in response:
    i+=1
    print(f"out i={i}: "+str(oline)[0:10])    
    if i<4: continue
    j = 0
    for iline in response:
        j+=1
        print(f"in  j={j}: "+str(iline)[0:10])        
        if j<2: continue
        i = 0
        break
```